# Linq to list query C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

There is a list of a class in my software with these properties :

 Name -- Quantity 

list may contains these data :

name1 -- 12 
name1 -- 10 
name2 -- 10 
name2 -- 5 
I need a output like this : 
name1 -- 22 
name2 -- 15

I can make this output with messy code (with for each and etc) but how can I provide this with LINQ query ?

Comment: So you want to sum up certain variables for each class instance in the list?

Comment: My current refactoring tool of choice (ReSharper) will automatically convert from "messy" code to LINQ and vice versa, by the way.

Comment: @kmkemp I use ReSharper , due my "messy" code contains if conditions it did not refactor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) and [Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx).

It would look similar to:

```
var values = theCollection
                .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(i => i.Value) });

foreach(var value in values)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", value.Name, value.Total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sum and GroupBy](http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2007/11/11/LINQSumAndGroupBy.aspx) and then print the results.